# GCC 9 ICE (internal compiler error) when using coverage

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, internals

Using EDG frontend compiler to generate CPP code started to crash on GCC 9/10/11, used to work on GCC 6.3.0.

```
   during IPA pass: profile
<file_name>.m4: In function 'void <function_name>(int)':
<file_name>.m4:4232:1: internal compiler error: in coverage_begin_function, at coverage.c:656
0x59a1fa coverage_begin_function(unsigned int, unsigned int)
                /tmp/gcc-v9.3.0p3/gcc.source/gcc/coverage.c:458
0xad549a branch_prob(bool)
    /tmp/gcc-v9.3.0p3/gcc.source/gcc/profile.c:1233
0xc10212 tree_profiling
    /tmp/gcc-v9.3.0p3/gcc.source/gcc/tree-profile.c:793
0xc10212 execute
/tmp/gcc-v9.3.0p3/gcc.source/gcc/tree-profile.c:898
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can find the code on the link below "Bugzilla Bug 100788".

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved on B[ugzilla Bug 100788](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100788)

Threre is an issue on the GCC processor which crashes when it tries to process the`#line` directives during coverage compilation.

**Solution:** backport a patch from GCC 10 that fixes this issue

Comment: Oh, I see.  The crash isn't really in the preprocessor itself, but the preprocessor is generating incorrect `#line` directives which cause the later profile pass to crash.  So really two bugs, I guess.